# I had a trip to Mexico and the name of the city that I visited is/was Mexico City

Tags: grammar

should one use "is" or "was" in the following paragraph when mentioning the city he/she went to during a trip to Mexico? I think if I use "was" it might mean the city now has a different name ...

"I had a trip to Mexico and the the name of the city that I visited is/was Mexico City"

Thank you!

Comment: In this case, you would use *is* because Mexico City still has that name, regardless of when it was visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have worded your sentence you would say *... and the name of the city I visited **is** Mexico City.*  This is because you are referring to the *name* of the city.  The name of a city that still exists would be discussed in the present tense because the name of a city **is** that city's name.  You would only say it **was** the city's name if the city no longer existed or if it changed its name.

However, as a general rule we do not say, *The name of X was/is X,* when X is always referred to by its name.  For example, *I went to visit my friend and the name of my friend is Sarah.*  We would not say that.  We would just say, *I went to visit my friend Sarah.*  The same applies to a city.  We always call a city by its name (or nickname which would still follow the same rules).

You would say

> *I **took** a trip to Mexico and the city I visited **was** Mexico City.*

Notice the word *name* does not appear in that sentence.  We are no longer talking about the city's *name*.  We are now talking about the city.  Even though Mexico City still has the same name and still exists, your visit occurred in the past and *in the past* the city you visited **was** Mexico City. The *name* of the city that you visited in the past **is** Mexico City.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations!